# How to disable an specific button taking id in angular TYPESCRIPT?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

They are 3 cards, each of them have 1 button "Like", i alredy did the code to detect their ids, but now i want to know how to disable the button that has been click, and create a table in another component that display the informations of the button of the card that have been click

thank you very much in advance

**TS**

```
export class uneListe {
  id: number = 0;
  txt: string = '' ;

  image: string = '';
  titre: string = '';
  
}

export class AppComponent {

  public list: Array<uneListe> = [];
  public isDisabled:boolean=false;
  title = 'Projettodo';
constructor(){
    
    let likes:number = 0;
    let save:number = 0;
    ;


    let l: uneListe = { id: 1, titre : '1 Ultra - PINK'}
    this.list.push(l);
    l = { id: 2, titre : '2 Ultra - PINK'}
    this.list.push(l);
    l = { id: 3, titre : '3 Ultra - PINK'}
    this.list.push(l);
}

 idgets(n: uneListe){
      if (n) { console.log(n.id); }
      let whatid = n.id;
  }


 didLike(n: uneListe) {
      if (n) { console.log(n.id); }
    
  }
```

**html**

```
<mat-grid-list cols="3" rowHeight="1:2" >
  <div *ngFor="let element of list">
  <mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-card>
      <img src="{{element.image}}">
        <h2>{{element.titre}}</h2>
        <p>{{element.txt}}</p>
        <button  (click) ="didLike(element)" [disabled]="isDisabled">LIKE</button>
        <button   (click) ="didsave(element)" >SAVE</button>
    </mat-card>
  </mat-grid-tile>
</div>
</mat-grid-list>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disable button there are multiple ways.
You can do it directly by the id like this

```
document.getElementById("myID").disabled = true;
```

Other possible solution is to extend your data model with property disabled / clicked or whatever and the use it in condition like this

```
 let l: uneListe = { id: 1, titre : '1 Ultra - PINK', clicked: false}
```

and then in template you will set it like this

```
<button  (click) ="didLike(element)" [disabled]="element.clicked">LIKE</button>
```

Dont forget to toggle the value of clicked in this case. You can either do it in didLike method or like this

```
 <button  (click) ="didLike(element); elemenet.clicked = !element.clicked" [disabled]="element.clicked">LIKE</button>
```